# How to read date from file into structure?

Tags: c

I had really hard time in finding solution mostly because popular searchers think that data and date are the same, by date i mean e.g 11/10/2014 9:00.

Alright so i have a structure

```
struct Rezervations{
    char user_login[10];
    int room_number;
    char date[40];
} rezervations[100];
```

i have file "reservations.txt" where I'm holding my data's like this:

> LOGIN1;5;11/10/14 09:00:00; LOGIN2;1;12/10/14 09:00:00;

etc

To this point i was reading this kind of files using `if` like this

```
int loadReservation()
{
    char reserved[200];
    char temNumber[2];
    fp=fopen("rezervations.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%s", reserved);
    int i;
    int z=0;
    int k=0;
        char temp[10];
    for(i=0;i<strlen(reserved);i++)
    {
        int j=0;
        while(reserved[i]!=59)
        {
            temp[j]=reserved[i];
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        if (z==0||z%3==0)
            {
            memcpy(reservations[k].user_login,temp,j);
        }
            else if (z==1||z%3==1)
            {
            memcpy(tempLiczba,temp,j);
            reservations[k].room_number = tempLiczba[0] - '0';
        } 
            else if (z==2||z%3==2)
            {
            memcpy(reservations[k].date,temp,j);
            k++;
        }
        z++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return k;
}
```

I know this code is messy but I hope u will see what I'm trying to accomplish here. I haven't used `malloc` yet (with `reserved` e.g) but thats no my question, I'd like to know how to read this date.
but unfortunately for me with date it stopped working. My guess it stopped working because my date contains `/` and `:` but I have no idea how to bypass it. This date is generated by `strftime()` and I would like not to change it.
Also if you can look at `rezervations[k].room_number = tempLiczba[0] - '0';` because that's how I'm reading integer from text file.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's probably a hundred ways to achieve this in C, but one (easy one) might be to use one of the variants of sscanf.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm

Example/pseudocode

```
char * line_from_file = read_next_line();
sscanf(line_from_file, "%s;%d;%s", rezervations[k].user_login, &rezervations[k].room_number, rezervations[k].date);
```

Edit:

Maybe %s only stops reading on whitespace, and as yours is semicolon seperated, you may need something like

```
sscanf(line_from_file, "%[^;];%d;%[^;]", ...)
```

Comment: sorry have to reverse it, for some reason it does not read hours and minutes. `sscanf(reserved, "%[^;];%d;%[^;]", reserved[k].login_uzytkownika, &reserved[k].numer_sali, reserved[k].data);` probably because of whitespace?